# IntelliJ IDEA with PHP plugin: project explorer icons blinking

Tags: php, intellij-idea

1. How to reproduce problem:

   - Create new project of "PHP Empty project" type
   - Create arbitrary php file, for example test.php
   - Until code of this file doesn't contain one and only one class, icon of such file is plain PHP icon (see picture 1), and everthing is pretty OK
   - If file contains one PHP class, icon in project explorer tool window changes to "Class icon" like in Java classes (picture 2). Furthermore, every editing in such file leads to repainting icon, blinking from PHP icon to "Java class" icon. This behavior is very annoying.
2. I can assume, that some java code inspection feauture inside IDE performs on-fly checks, "thinks" that this code is Java class, and repaints icons inside project explorer, making this in struggle with PHP plugin. By the way, PHPStorm IDE doesn't affected by this problem.
3. Question itself: Does anybody know how to prevent this blinking? Maybe some hidden options to disable such "content-relating" checks, or some way to tell IDE directly that this file is PHP, not Java class and will never be :)
4. Pictures mentioned in p.1

[image: Picture 1 - PHP icon]
[image: Picture 2 - Blinking Java class icon]

Thanks for your attention

Comment: Not exactly a code-related question. Did you try to contact the developer of the software? If it is a bug I think they would like to know about it.

Comment: There's already an issue opened on software site. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-32948 . It seems resolved in the next release

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned in comments, this is existing bug, and I have to wait for fix.
Thank You chumkiu!